# Waiting in android app

Tags: android, multithreading, wait

So I'm using in my android program A thread to wait a second or more, but sometimes it does it wright and sometimes it doesn't wait at all, so is there maybe another way to wait a couple of seconds?

```
Thread logotimer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(1500);
            Intent leveloverview = new Intent("com.technopolisapp.FROGLEVEL");
            startActivity(leveloverview);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            finish();
        }
    }
};

logotimer.start();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead the thread sleeping concept you can use Handler...

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        Intent leveloverview = new Intent("com.technopolisapp.FROGLEVEL");
        startActivity(leveloverview);
    }
}, 5000);
```

This code may be helpful for you...

Comment: I tryed this method but it still gets problems first was it this: can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(). Then I added Looper.prepare(). But then came the problem: only one looper may be created per thread

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the Timer class, which creates a new thread that will run whatever TimerTask (aka method) you specify once a certain time has elapsed. You can also schedule the timer to repeat at certain intervals.

Here's the Timer class: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Here's a basic implementation of a Timer: http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12