# Thread.Sleep() Android UI

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I'm working on a memory game for Android and I'm having a problem. When the user taps the second image - if the images are not the same I want the second image to show for 1, 2 seconds.

What I've tried is to sleep for 1-2 sec. the UI thread after the second image is activated - but this doesn't seem to work - the second image doesn't seem to show! (only the first images is showed)

Here's my code:

```
public void whenTapedImage(View v, int position)
{
    i++;
    ImageView imgV=(ImageView)v;
    if(i%2!=0)
    {
        firstClick=position;
        imgV.setImageResource(im.images.get(firstClick));           
    }
    else
    {   
        secondClick=position;
        imgV.setImageResource(im.images.get(secondClick));                      
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            if(!(im.images.get(firstClick).equals(im.images.get(secondClick))))
            {
                Toast.makeText(easyGame.this, "Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                im.notifyDataSetChanged();
                gridview.setAdapter(im);
                gridview.invalidate();
                aux=player1Turn;
                player1Turn=player2Turn;
                player2Turn=aux;
            }
            else{
                done=done+2;
                ImageAdapter.keepVisibleViews.add(firstClick);
                ImageAdapter.keepVisibleViews.add(secondClick);
                if(player1Turn==true)
                {
                    player1Score++;
                    String score=Integer.toString(player1Score);
                    score1.setText(score);
                }
                if(player2Turn==true)
                {
                    player2Score++;
                    String score=Integer.toString(player2Score);
                    score2.setText(score);
                }
            }   
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }           
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `but this doesn't seem to work.` That's not a good way to ask a question. What doesn't work about it?

Comment: @Falmarri - I agree it's not a great way to ask the question, but in this case the body of the question is not really that important, since the title includes something well known to be incompatible with the event-driven architecture of the android ui.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428726/waiting-in-android-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to [Waiting in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428726/waiting-in-android-app)

Try following the solution posted there and use the [Timer Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 7):

You must not sleep the UI thread as this would prevent android from delivering any other events to your activity's UI.

Instead, do something such as use a timer and have the timer's method use the run on ui thread facility to make the desired postponed change.

For robustness you may need to implement a state machine (either formally, or in effect) to keep track of what is supposed to be happening - you'll need to decide if the current delay should be aborted or enforced if another button is pushed, and make the state machine treat that appropriately.