# Does Thread.sleep() makes the UI Thread to sleep?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Will this make the current UI thread to sleep?

```
try 
{
   Thread.sleep(20);
   onProgressUpdate(i);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002657/thread-sleep-android-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling sleep on the ui thread it blocks the ui thread. Do not call sleep on the ui thread. You should not block the ui thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

You will get ANR

If you implement `Thread` or `HandlerThread`, be sure that your UI thread does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete—do not call `Thread.wait()` or `Thread.sleep()`.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Also check the topic under How to Avoid ANRs

Answer (score 3):

Only if *called* from the UI thread.

Comment: And just to add, you should NEVER sleep the ui thread. Your app will become unresponsive, and ask the user if they want to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep(time)` will causes the thread which sent this message to sleep for the given interval of time. So if you call it in UI thread, it will affect the UI thread. As far as android is concerned it is not advised to obstruct UI thread in any way, otherwise it will result in ANR - application not responding.

You can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, any static method in the language can be invoked on an object reference instead of the class. But that doesn't change the functionality: Thread.sleep() is a static method that puts the current thread to sleep.