# android try/catch execute sequence

Tags: android, android-handler

what I want to achieve is Upon click, app shows toasts message "TEXT1", and keeps showing TEXT1 until finish other function call 20 times at a random interval/delay. After calling function,shows toast message "TEXT2". My problem: TEXT1 does not show until app finishes function call. and TEXT1 keeps up for the time it takes to execute 20 times function call,then TEXT2 shows up.My code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.example:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please wait until finish",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int i = 0;
                while (i <= 19 ){

                    int delay = new Random().nextInt(5000);
                    try {
                            Thread.sleep(delay);
                        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    //some function here
                    i++;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Finished",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Never block the UI thread!

All user interface operations are handled in the UI thread. If you block the UI thread with a `Thread.sleep` call, an ANR (Application Not Responding) will occur. Moreover, `Thread.sleep` is never the right way to create timers, unless you are writing the core heartbeat of a worker thread.

Instead, you should use `Handler.postDelayed`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Random random = new Random();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            count++;
            if(count > 20) { // 20 times passed
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Finished", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait until finish", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            handler.postDelayed(this, random.nextInt(5000));
        }
    };
    runnable.run();
}
```

Edit: the OP wanted to use something like this. https://gist.github.com/SOF3/07c3c110aa214fcdd752e95573b7076f

See also:

- [Android - running a method periodically using postDelayed() call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10845172/3990767)
- [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3072173/3990767)
- [Waiting in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10428726/3990767)

Comment: this method calls my function at a FIXED interval,which is not I want.

Comment: Then just change the 1000 to your random number. But didn't you say that you want the toast message to show up consistently?

Comment: yes, I did.so basically my code should be something like:
`final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   
  }
}, Myrandomnumber);` ?

Comment: Delay it with `random.nextInt()`. Make the `Random` object `final`. Create a class field that stores how many times this runnable has been called. Editing in a minute to show you how.

Comment: @tikael Edited.

Comment: I tested, the toast msg does not show...though the UI keeps updating.

Comment: Does it show the first time? Did you add the last line `runnable.run()`? It is unreasonable that it doesn't show any toasts (unless you have problems your side), because the runnable must at least show a toast either way, postDelayed or not.

Comment: it does not and I did add the runnable.run()

Comment: @tikael Add a logcat message in the `run` method inside the Runnable. If your code is run, that logcat message must show. If the logcat message shows but the toast doesn't show, your toast has a problem.

Comment: I added `Log.i(TAG,"yes"); ` right under the "please wait..."and I can see TAG:yes in the logcat--info window..still no toast message...so weird.

Comment: Try changing your context? Maybe you are using the wrong context.

Comment: one more thing, the whole function calls toast for each loop, is there a way to show the "please wait.." constantly? maybe I should customize the `Toast.LENGTH`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123623/discussion-between-pemapmodder-and-tikael).